# no me funciona el try catch en php

Tags: php7, excepciones, try-catch, symfony4

Tengo mi sistema, estoy utilizando symfony y tengo el siguiente codigo dentro de mi archivo .php

```
try{
            $ds = @ldap_connect($servidor, $puerto);
        }catch (UndefinedFunctionError  $e){
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
                'noticeerror',
                'Error con la funcionalidad LDAP. Por favor rectificar tener instalado la extension php_ldap '
            );
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('inicio'));
        }
```

el problema es q al no estar definida la funcion ldap_connect pues siempre me salta la pag de error de UndefinedFunctionError  cdo lo q kiero es q capture el error y siga con el funcionamiento del sistema normal, o sea nunca entra al catch, no se porq no lo esta haciendo, si me pueden dar alguna idea, graciasss

[image: Siempre salta el error!! y no es lo q kiero]

Comment: Es un fatal error, dice claramente que la función no está definida, por lo que al momento de intentarlo, no puede hacer nada... no es que la función falle... es que NO EXISTE.

Comment: @Excorpion claro q la funcion no esta definida pero lo q necesito es q no me salte el error y siga el funcionamiento del sistema no c si me entiendes q siga con el codigo q esta dentro del catch

Comment: Te va a saltar siempre, por que es un error fatal... podrías tratar a usar esta respuesta como guia. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116995/is-it-possible-in-php-to-prevent-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function

Comment: @Excorpion perfecto me sirvio esa respuesta como guia fue solo cambiar UndefinedFunctionError  $e por  \Error $e                           Muchas Gracias

Comment: recuerda leer los comentarios igual, para el php que tengas

Comment: @Excorpion si gracias